# Wrong Animation with OpenGL and Assimp

Tags: opengl, assimp

im currently trying to render an Animation with OpenGL. I load the Model and the animation with Assimp.net an C# wrapper from Assip. Rendering the Mesh works fine but everytime when i try to update the animation i get the following result.

[image]

As the files are to long you can find the complete vs solution here https://github.com/Andy16823/Animation-Bug

Thanks in advance